# ListDataProvider.getList().remove doesn't use the KeyProvider

Tags: gwt, celltable, gwt-celltable

Calling the ListDataProvider.getList().remove(...) doesn't use the KeyProvider passed in constructor. Is this a GWT bug or is it supposed to work like this?
I've attached the relevant unit test below.

Thank you,

```
    TestVO ri1 = new TestVO();
    ri1.setId(null);
    ri1.setName("msg1");
    TestVO ri2 = new TestVO();
    ri2.setId(null);
    ri2.setName("msg2");
    TestVO ri3 = new TestVO();
    ri3.setId(null);
    ri3.setName("msg2");

    ListDataProvider<TestVO> ldp = new ListDataProvider<>(new ProvidesKey<TestVO>() {
      @Override
      public Object getKey(TestVO pItem) {
        System.out.println("this never gets invoked");
        return pItem.getMessageType();
      }
    });
    ldp.setList(Lists.newArrayList(ri1, ri2));

    ldp.getList().remove(ri3);

    //this currently fails, actual size is 1 as it removes ri2
    assertEquals(2, ldp.getList().size());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not a bug and no it doesn't use the `getKey` implementation you provided for finding the element in that list, because that method is used for other operations. Bear with me...

`ListDataProvider` uses a `ListWrapper` which implements the `List` interface and `ListWrapper` is backed by an ordinary `List` that holds your objects. The `ListWrapper` has implementation for the methods you are using (add, set, remove etc) that manipulate the `List` that you passed `Lists.newArrayList(ri1, ri2)`.

This manipulation is accomplished by calling, among others, the standard operations of the `List` interface. So what is being called to determine which object should be removed is `indexOf` which in let's say `ArrayList` (that's what you are passing, so that's what is being used) uses (as you would expect) the `equals` method of `TestVO` which in case you haven't overriden is the one that you can find in the `Object` class.

The `getKey` method that you provide is being used to identify the row inside a list of rows (inside the display you are using, like `DataGrid`). This can be found in `AbstractDataProvider`. This method, that calls your method, is called by other methods (see what I did there :P) all over the place in order to identify the row that needs some action. An example would be an update of a row inside a `DataGrid`. The method that will determine which row was updated is the method you provided. So if your implementation doesn't provide a unique key, you will have indication of an update for all the rows with the same key. So be careful.

```
  /**
   * Get the key for a list item. The default implementation returns the item
   * itself.
   *
   * @param item the list item
   * @return the key that represents the item
   */
  public Object getKey(T item) {
    return keyProvider == null ? item : keyProvider.getKey(item);
  }
```

The implementation of `indexOf` in `ArrayList`

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This is the implemention of GWT

```
/**
 * Construct a new {@link ListWrapper} that delegates flush calls to the
 * specified delegate.
 *
 * @param list the list to wrap
 * @param delegate the delegate
 * @param offset the offset of this list
 */
private ListWrapper(List<T> list, ListWrapper delegate, int offset) {
  this.list = list;
  this.delegate = delegate;
  this.offset = offset;
}

@Override
public void add(int index, T element) {
  try {
    list.add(index, element);
    minModified = Math.min(minModified, index);
    maxModified = size();
    modified = true;
    flush();
  } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(e.getMessage());
  }
}
@Override
public T remove(int index) {
  try {
    T toRet = list.remove(index);
    minModified = Math.min(minModified, index);
    maxModified = size();
    modified = true;
    flush();
    return toRet;
  } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(e.getMessage());
  }
}

@Override
public boolean remove(Object o) {
  int index = indexOf(o);
  if (index == -1) {
    return false;
  }
  remove(index);
  return true;
}

public void setList(List<T> listToWrap) {
  listWrapper = new ListWrapper(listToWrap);
  listWrapper.minModified = 0;
  listWrapper.maxModified = listWrapper.size();
  listWrapper.modified = true;
  flush();
}

public List<T> getList() {
  return listWrapper;
}
```